# rsync: opendir failed: Permission denied (13) from a Synology DSM7 server with synoacl

Tags: rsync, acl, accounts, synology

I have `rsyncd` running as `SynoRsyncd` sharing the `/volume1` module :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ ps -O user:20 -C rsync
  PID USER                 S TTY          TIME COMMAND
14290 SynoRsyncd           S ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/rsync --daemon
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ cat /etc/rsyncd.conf
#refuse options = acls
#motd file = /etc/rsyncd.motd
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
use chroot = no
read only = yes
dont compress = aac *.aiff *.aif *.avi *.m2ts *.m4v *.mov *.MOV *.mp4 *.mpg *.mx                  f *.tif *.wav *.png *.zip
exclude = .DS_Store* desktop.ini \#recycle/

[volume1]
path = /volume1
[volume2]
path = /volume2
[volume3]
path = /volume3
```

I want to copy `/volume1/watch_adn` from another server and I get a `rsync: opendir "watch_adn" (in volume1) failed: Permission denied (13)` error :

```bash
[root@rsyncClient ~]# syncCommand="rsync --stats -Hauv -h -P";$syncCommand --log-file=$HOME/log/synchro_detailed_ADN_$(date +%Y%m%d).log "rsync://t1-sma@PAR-ADN-SYN02:/volume1/watch_adn" /ring/0/share/Archives_ADN/
receiving incremental file list
rsync: opendir "watch_adn" (in volume1) failed: Permission denied (13)

Number of files: 1 (dir: 1)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 120
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 21
Total bytes received: 132

sent 21 bytes  received 132 bytes  306.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1651) [generator=3.1.2]
```

And on the `rsyncServer`, I get :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ tail -5 /var/log/rsyncd.log
2022/09/14 12:25:35 [13072] name lookup failed for 172.16.15.37: Name or service not known
2022/09/14 12:25:35 [13072] connect from UNKNOWN (172.16.15.37)
2022/09/14 12:25:35 [13072] rsync on volume1/watch_adn from UNKNOWN (172.16.15.37)
2022/09/14 12:25:35 [13072] building file list
2022/09/14 12:25:35 [13072] rsync: opendir "watch_adn" (in volume1) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

Although everyone can read `/volume1/watch_adn` :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ ll -d /volume1/watch_adn
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 root root 166 Aug 24 15:58 /volume1/watch_adn
```

`getfacl` is not installed. Showing if `/volume1` is mounted with acl :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ getfacl /volume1/watch_adn/
-sh: getfacl: command not found
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ mount | grep /volume1 | grep acl
/dev/mapper/cachedev_2 on /volume1 type btrfs (rw,nodev,relatime,ssd,synoacl,space_cache=v2,auto_reclaim_space,metadata_ratio=50,subvolid=257,subvol=/@syno)
```

They were using a `synoacl` mount option, showing those ACLs :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ synoacltool -get /volume1/watch_adn/
ACL version: 1
Archive: has_ACL,is_support_ACL
Owner: [root(user)]
---------------------
         [0] group:administrators:allow:rwxpdDaARWc--:fd-- (level:0)
         [1] group:ORION\vpn_utilisateurs_sysadmin:allow:rwxpdDaARWc--:fd-- (level:0)
         [2] user::allow:r-x---a-R-c--:fd-- (level:0)
         [3] group:Watch-ADN_R:allow:r-x---a-R-c--:fd-- (level:0)
         [4] group:Watch_ADN_RW:allow:rwxpdDaARWc--:fd-- (level:0)
         [5] user::allow:r-x---a-R-c--:fd-- (level:0)
         [6] group:ORION\adn:allow:rwxpdDaARWc--:fd-- (level:0)
```

I added the read rights for `SynoRsyncd` and restarted `rsyncd.service` :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ sudo synoacltool -add /volume1/watch_adn user:SynoRsyncd:allow:r-x-----R-c--:fd--
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ synoacltool -get /volume1/watch_adn | grep rsyncd -i
         [2] user:SynoRsyncd:allow:r-x-----R-c--:fd-- (level:0)
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ sudo systemctl restart rsyncd.service
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ tail -5 /var/log/rsyncd.log
2022/09/14 15:45:33 [10650] rsync on volume1/watch_adn from UNKNOWN (172.16.15.37)
2022/09/14 15:45:34 [10650] building file list
2022/09/14 15:45:34 [10650] rsync: opendir "watch_adn" (in volume1) failed: Permission denied (13)
2022/09/14 15:50:04 [21952] sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
2022/09/14 15:50:04 [13486] rsyncd version 3.1.2 starting, listening on port 873
```

Showing the ACLs on /volume1 :

```bash
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ synoacltool -get /volume1
(synoacltool.c, 489)It is Linux mode
[user@rsyncServer ~] $ ll -d /volume1
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 482 Sep 14 16:09 /volume1
```

I am dealing with a Synology DSMv7 server based on a SystemD Linux.

`sudo -u SynoRsyncd ls -al /volume1/watch_adn` works fine.

Comment: What permissions files have below /volume1/watch_adn? Is it some webui configuration for  /volume1/watch_adn or /volume1?

Comment: @gapsf The same as `/volume1/watch_adn`,  they have been inherited.

Comment: Do it have su or runuser command?

Comment: @gapsf It has both `sudo` and `su` commands.

Comment: Is it SynoRsyncd user enabled in webui?

Comment: https://kb.synology.com/en-us/DSM/help/DSM/AdminCenter/file_rsync?version=7

Comment: @gapsf But the `rsyncd.service` user (`SynoRsyncd`) is not in the `Control Panel->User & Group` GUI, weird, isn't it ? Moreover I could where the `rsyncd.service` specifies it must start as `SynoRsyncd` : it is not in the `systemctl cat rsyncd.service`.

Comment: Add user you use to connect like here
   https://serverfault.com/a/724515/149509

Comment: @gapsf Which one `SynoRsyncd ` or `t1-sma` ?

Comment: t1-sma you use it to connect

Comment: @gapsf Do I also need to add `SynoRsyncd` user to `Control Panel->User & Group` and to `Control Panel->File Services->rsync` ?

Comment: My guess is yes. Try without adding then add if not work. Why you didnt configure these all via webui?

Comment: rsync has its own "users". They not from host's users. You need them add to  Control Panel->File Services->rsync only (i guess)